# How to use javascript to make a 3d time picker like the alarm clock of iOS, with scroll animation?

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to make a 3d time picker (with perspective) as below (like the alarm clock of iOS).

And I want to trigger the scroll animation when I click a button.

1. I found many time pickers but it seems that they can only scroll when human touch, which is not what I want.
2. If I use the CSS animation `rotateX`, I can not change the opacity of each item when it's rotating.
3. So it seems that I have to write the animation myself, but I don't know how.

How could I make it?

[image: clock]

Answer (score 0):

For your second issue, I guess you could just use an overlapping element that is either semi-transparent or have a blend mode to the top and bottom (so just above and below your middle number)